# Extract data from a text file using Python in a specific format

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, file-io

I'm trying to extract pieces of data from a text file, then insert it into a CSV file, in order to do that I'm trying to get the data extracted and get it as prepared as possible to be able to insert it into the CSV file, I have a file full of text that looks like this:

```
Date       TimeStamp     Name    Action     Department        Duration

2022-04-02 01:35:21.3683 Jackson ClockedOut Team Sports Floor 08:06:05
2022-04-02 01:35:21.3683 Jackson ClockedOut Managment Floor 08:06:05
2022-04-02 01:35:21.3683 Jackson ClockedOut Front 08:06:05
```

The way I'm trying to reformat the data is:

```
Date       TimeStamp     Name    Action     Department        Duration

2022-04-02,01:35:21.3683,Jackson,ClockedOut,Team Sports Floor,08:06:05
2022-04-02,01:35:21.3683,Jackson,ClockedOut,Managment Floor,08:06:05
2022-04-02,01:35:21.3683,Jackson,ClockedOut,Front,08:06:05
```

The part I'm having the most trouble with is the Department, where I don't want any commas on.

here is the line that does the trimming and inserts commans into the string:

```
trim_string = " ".join(line.split()).replace(" ",",")
```

I'm new to python so any code snips of examples would also help me alot.

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing or tutorial service. Please [edit] your question and post [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), including example input, expected output, the actual output (if any), and the [*full text* of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146), *all as formatted text in the question itself.* Do not post images of text. The code should be a [mre].

Comment: Please show the code you're having trouble with.  Also, is the data file showing the *exact* layout, or is the Duration actually lined up under the header?

Comment: @MarkTolonen it's the exact layout, I just edited the question to show the line I have used that does the conversion

Answer (score 0):

If the only extra spaces are in the Department column, you could do this.  I am assuming you *don't* want a spaced header and a blank line in the CSV file as that would be odd.

```py
import csv

with open('input.txt', newline='') as fin, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as fout:
    reader = csv.reader(fin, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
    writer = csv.writer(fout)
    for line in reader:
        if not line: continue # to skip the blank line
        date,timestamp,name,action,*department,duration = line
        writer.writerow([date, timestamp, name, action, ' '.join(department), duration])
```

Output:

```
Date,TimeStamp,Name,Action,Department,Duration
2022-04-02,01:35:21.3683,Jackson,ClockedOut,Team Sports Floor,08:06:05
2022-04-02,01:35:21.3683,Jackson,ClockedOut,Managment Floor,08:06:05
2022-04-02,01:35:21.3683,Jackson,ClockedOut,Front,08:06:05
```